# How to impute an approximate Date of Birth from an age field in years?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, missing-data, imputation

I have some data with Date of birth information (in string format) and a column with Age in years like below:

| id | DOB | AGE_YEARS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1992-06-10 | 29 |
| 03 | 1991-01-10 | 30 |
| 02 | 20216-6-10 | 5 |

when using, `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'],errors='coerce')` the result is:

| id | DOB | AGE_YEARS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1992-06-10 | 29 |
| 03 | 1991-01-10 | 30 |
| 02 | NaN | 5 |

which is the correct output. However, I know the Age column is both correct and up to date (2021-05-31), is there a way to impute a rough DOB (row by row on the dataframe) by substracting the AGE_YEARS from the last updated date where the date of birth has nulls?

i.e.
`last_updated_date` = **2021-05-31**

`last_updated_date - AGE_YEARS = DOB`

Comment: calculate the approximate DOB as a pd.Series and use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)? Since this is only an approximation, a timedelta of 365.25 days should do as one year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combine_first` and `transform` to fill NaT:

```
last_updated_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-05-31')

df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].combine_first(
    df['AGE_YEARS'].transform(lambda x: last_updated_date - pd.DateOffset(years=x))
)
```

```
>>> df
   id        DOB  AGE_YEARS
0   1 1992-06-10         29
1   3 1991-01-10         30
2   2 2016-05-31          5
```

Comment: Produces this error: ValueError: Transform function failed

Comment: It worked for your sample. What is the difference between your real data and your sample?

Comment: age was in float, just casted to int and it worked. thanks